# What (if anything) is this GPU compute or shader pattern called?

Tags: cuda, gpu, shader, opencl, gpgpu

Firstly, please note this could equally be applied to writing graphics shaders as to GPGPU code, though my interest is GPGPU which is why the example code is "compute-like".

We all know GPUs cannot really "do" branching code efficiently, due to inherent limitations of SIMD  processors.

A pattern I have used several times, and I am surely not alone, is to refactor the kernel into multiple kernels, the first of which determines which code branch a particular work item is on,  and the remainder of which execute (non-branching) code for one particular code branch only.

I have in the past always used non-device code after the first kernel runs in order to partition the work items into separate arrays (according to code branch id) before invoking the branchless kernels, though in what I'm presenting here I'm using atomically incrementing indices to do the partitioning as part of the first (branch-determining) kernel. I'm calling this the "n + 1 kernels" pattern but I imagine it probably has another name already.

The following is generic GPU compute pseudocode (though it's close to OpenCL, and some terminology is probably from OpenCL-land):

```
// n+1 kernels pattern

// device code (generic gpgpu language) without n+1 kernels pattern:

kernel void oneKernel(const int[] intArray, const float[] floatArray, float[] out) {
    int globalId = getId();
    int thisInt = intArray[globalId];
    float thisFloat = floatArray[globalId];
    
    if (someCondition(thisInt, thisFloat)) {
        if (someOtherCondition(thisInt)) {
            out[globalId] = expensiveCalc0(thisInt, thisFloat);
        } else {
            out[globalId] = expensiveCalc1(thisInt, thisFloat);
        }
    } else {
        out[globalId] += expensiveCalc2(thisInt, thisFloat);
    }
}

// Device code using n+1 kernels pattern: first call createBranchMappings():

kernel void createBranchMappings(const int[] intArray, const float[] floatArray, int[][] globalIdsByBranch, volatile int[] nextIndexByBranch) {
    int globalId = getId();
    int thisInt = intArray[globalId];
    float thisFloat = floatArray[globalId];
    int branchId;
    
    // someCondition is evaluated by all threads in lock step... 
    if (someCondition(thisInt, thisFloat)) {
        // ... but someOtherCondition is not. Would be possible but very convoluted (using even more kernels) to avoid losing 
        // lockstep here, and unlikely I'd guess to be beneficial unless someOtherCondition were itself very expensive. 
        // Also note use of atomics later on breaks true lockstep in any case
        if (someOtherCondition(thisInt)) {
            branchId = 0;
        } else {
            branchId = 1;
        }
    } else {
        branchId = 2;
    }
    globalIdsByBranch[branchId][atomic_add(&nextIndexByBranch[branchId], 1)] = globalId;
}

// Then call branch0()
// getId() ranges from 0 to number of elements for which branchId == 0
// (which we can get from nextIndexByBranch after calling createBranchMappings()).
// There is no branching at all while running this kernel, threads remain in lockstep. 

kernel void branch0(const int[] intArray, const float[] floatArray, const int[][] globalIdsByBranch, float[] out) {
    int indexInThisBranch = getId();
    int globalIndex = globalIdsByBranch[0][indexInThisBranch];
    int thisInt = intArray[globalIndex];
    float thisFloat = floatArray[globalIndex];
    out[globalIndex] = expensiveCalc0(thisInt, thisFloat); 
}

// Then call branch1() ... then branch2() and we are done. branch1() and branch2() look just like branch0() except they
// call expensiveCalc1 and expensiveCalc2 rather than expensiveCalc0.
```

Some questions.

1. Assuming this approach is nothing new, does it have a name?
2. Is there a better way than the one presented here for partitioning the work items for presentation to the branchN() kernels? In particular, is it possible to avoid the cost of using atomics? I suspect there's a better approach in which each workgroup does this without using atomics and atomics are only needed (after a barrier) at the global level... but I'm not very *au fait* with doing workgroup level stuff.
3. Anecdotally, this approach has worked for me (improved execution times); is there some reason to assume I have been lucky and that this approach is not always useful?
4. It seems to me that a GPGPU language compiler could actually do this code transformation for you (internally and transparently) for all branching kernels. But given that the advice always seems to be that GPUs cannot do branching efficiently, it would seem that they *aren't* doing this. So why not?

Thanks

Comment: Did you forget to remove the i, from your function arguments in createBranchMappings()? For the setup you have here, you could probably refactor createBranchMappings() to be branchless.

Comment: *"... this approach is not always useful?"* This approach works well in your case mainly because the computation is expensive. When it is not, the cost of launching new kernels and writing/reading data in global memory can be more expensive than doing both the if/else computations. This is especially true on recent GPUs which tends to have a higher computational intensity (so memory accesses are relatively more expensive) Besides, when there is no warp divergence, conditions are AFAIK quite cheap (since only one path is computed, not the two, though a check of divergence is still needed).

Comment: @SimonGoater Yes! Thank for pointing that out, removed i now. Buthe kernel here is just a toy, for exposition purposes of course.

Comment: *"GPGPU language compiler could actually do this code transformation for you (internally and transparently)"* The remapping step is particularly expensive so I do not think this is a good idea to always do that automatically/transparently/blindly. Sometimes, a block remapping is significantly cheaper and good enough to (mostly) avoid warp divergence. This avoid using a global expensive atomic operation nor any complicated global remapping code and so it tends to scale better. The automatic transformation make more sense for a higher-level language to me (unless it can be manually controlled).

Comment: By the way, be aware that some code could be shared between the computational functions and/or conditions (not to mention the indexing which can sometimes be complex and rather expensive in >2D). Sometimes it is better to recompute things (for memory-bound codes), sometimes to store results (for compute-bound codes), sometimes to do things on-the-fly and pay the cost of warp divergence.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I would not propose that the compiler would do this for all kernels automatically. Rather a model similar to (e.g.) Java HotSpot compiler, where both static code analysis and real metrics determine exactly what optimisations the compiler makes. (I'm not suggesting that would be simple, though!)

Comment: *"is it possible to avoid the cost of using atomics?"* Yes, typically using a scan pattern. This is not trivial to do manually efficiently. AFAIK, CUB (CUDA) provides primitives for that. IDK for OpenCL.

Comment: I don't know what it's called. You could give it a name. 'Branch Serialisation'? 'De-Branching'? 'Branch Re-Factoring'? ...

Comment: @SimonGoater "Branch Serialisation" is pretty good I think.

Comment: Condition hoisting is sometimes mentioned. The most typical use case is for kernels operating on rectangular arrays, with different handling of edges and inner parts (e.g., convolution). A common solution is to issue an inner kernel and sides kernel separately. In this case, of course, condition is pre-calculated and no initial scan pass is needed. Some OpenCL implementations experimented with automating this optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get similar (if not exact same) effect by just sorting the global id values on their branch-id values and running all in same kernel (you'd lose performance only on those transition point in a single warp, 1 warp max per branch id). This is called sorting. Processing a sorted array is faster. But since you are also separating the sorted chunks into their own containers, its called binning.

Comment: I would rather call it N-way partitioning at least for small N. But the boundary is certainly fluid. On the other hand one doesn't need the partition point(s) for this approach, so maybe sorting is actually the better description.

Comment: This is something I realised a couple of days after posting. Though there are still three kernels required, unless I'm missing something? The first kernel determines the branchId; the second does a bitonic (or other parallel sort) sort on the branchIds; the third processes all the branches together (just a switch on branchId is fine, divergence only happens at the boundaries between branchIds). But unless I've missed something (in which case please explain!) the three stages require distinct kernels, since there is no such thing (as I understand it) as a global memory barrier for GPU.

Comment: Another alternative would be to do the sort on CPU between the other two kernels, since from what I've read GPU sort is actually not typically faster than parallel CPU sort except for extremely large N. Though that way there is extra copying between RAM and VRAM.

Comment: Probably sorting on CPU is faster if data is already in cache and not too big. Bitonic sort was faster in my experience. Just use dynamic parallelism to re-launch sub kernels by gpu.